When using log4net.Ext.Json how do I get collection, dictionaries, and objects that are created on the fly
If I add a collection, dictionary, or an object to logger properties. They are not static, they are generated during production and can vary in content lenght.
var queryParams = request.QueryString.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => request.QueryString[k]);
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["QueryParams"] = queryParams;

var testCollection = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ACollection"] = testCollection;

var obj = new { Prop1 = "value", Prop2 = 5 };
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["AObject"] = obj;


I want the output to look like this:
{
  ...
  "QueryParams": {
    "Param1": "value1",
    "Param2": "value2",
  },
  "ACollection": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ],
  "AObject": {
    "Prop1": "value",
    "Prop2": 5
  }
  ...
}

How do I get log4net.Ext.Json to output them correctly?
Also, if null or empty I would like them to be left out, not shown as null or an empty collection.
